# Combine Lines based on pattern

Tags: vb.net

Sorry for being very specific, some pointers on best way forward would be great
I have the following data in a text file.

```
1234-5678
SK3
2345-6789
R306
R550
R551
R552
R553
R554
R555
3456-7890
RL573
RL574
RL575
```

and I need to write to a new text file

```
1234-5678 SK3
2345-6789 R306
2345-6789 R550
2345-6789 R551
2345-6789 R552
2345-6789 R553
2345-6789 R554
2345-6789 R555
3456-7890 RL573
3456-7890 RL574
3456-7890 RL575
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first entry of your file is a prefix, and all prefixes containing "-":

If the file is large, you should use a stream instead of loading to a List.

Code is C#-ish meta code, will work in VB.NET also, if you use the right syntax.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
List<string> lines = file.ReadAllLines("yourfile.txt");

foreach (String line in lines) {
    string prefix;
    if (line.Contains("-")) {
       prefix = line + " ";
    } else {
       sb.appendline(prefix + line);
    }    
}

// save content of StringBuilder to file
```

Streamreader will work as follows:

```
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
 {
     string prefix;

     while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
     {
         String line = sr.readLine();

         if (line.Contains("-")){
            prefix = line + " ";
         } else {         
            sb.appendline(prefix + line);
         }           
     }
 }
```

VB.Net version:

```
Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
Dim Prefix As String = String.Empty

Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("[Input File Path]")
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        Dim Line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        If Line.Contains("-"c) Then
            Prefix = Line & " "
        Else
            sb.AppendLine(Prefix & Line)
        End If
    End While
End Using

Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("[Output File Path]")
    writer.WriteLine(sb)
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look

Comment: Thanks works a treat, didn't have to edit your code except for initial text file and output text file

Comment: @PaulJ Please thank the one who answer by accepting his answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Comment: Hi Mary
Thanks for pointing out my lack of etiquette, I've now marked as answered